# Global variables in Java for cross-class data

Tags: java, swing, class, variables, jframe

Ok, what I am trying to do is use JFrame for the window and Java for the processing. And I am trying to transfer the players Username from one class to another. With this being said. I have looked everywhere on the internet and people have told them what to do, but not explained why this is so.

**UserData.Java**

```
public class UserData
{
    String Username;
    int CashPouch;
    public UserData(String Username, int CashPouch)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.CashPouch  = CashPouch;
    }
    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

**Starting class**

```
private void ContinueBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)        
{                                            
    String Username = UsernameField.getText().toString();
    if(!"".equals(Username)){
        this.setVisible(false);
        new Game().setVisible(true);
        //This is where I want to save the Username from the local variable username as above.
    } else {
    }
}
```

**Second Class**

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //This is where I would like to access the Username variable to set it below.
    UserDsp.setText(Username);
```

Apologies for the length, been struggling to do this for ages and like I explained. I have looked everywhere for how to do this, and I can make it work for several examples but not this one. Can someone please offer a solution but explain in simple terms how I go about doing this so I can do it in future.
Cheers. :)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: A bit off topic, but your variables should begin with a lower case letter. This helps distinguish between a variable and a class, which should begin with an upper case letter. That's why in the code snippets above your variables are formatted like class names. Changing this will help people to read your code.

Comment: on topic now, which username variable would you like to access? There is a username that is a member variable of the UserData class and a username variable in the starting class. Can you please explain a little clearer exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Normally, you would pass the username you collected when the button is pressed as a parameter to a method on the object that needs to know that value. Isn't it the `Game` object that needs the username? What if you passed it to the constructor of `Game`? Or maybe create a `UserData` in your listener and pass that to the `Game` constructor.

Comment: I also suggest you have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb,like most programming languages, global variables (in this case `static` variables) represent a risk and are generally a sign of bad design. Generally speaking you should avoid them where ever possible and use other techniques.  The more complex a program becomes, the easier it will be to completely screw up your state

Answer (score 0):

Java basics involves Objects & Classes.
Your answer depends on understanding those concepts.
You could check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) for information regarding Objects & Classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common enough issue which you will face just about all the time in the development life.

While there are a few ways you might do this, you have to appreciate which ones are going to serve you in the long run.

As a general rule of thumb, like most programming languages, global variables (in this case static variables) represent a risk and are generally a sign of bad design. Generally speaking you should avoid them where ever possible and use other techniques. The more complex a program becomes, the easier it will be to completely screw up your state.

The simplest solution would be to simply pass the information that you other classes are interested to them directly, either via the class constructor or via a method call.  See [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

There are other approaches, such as [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), producer/consumer and other [behavioral patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/behavioral-patterns/) which would also be applicable, but they work on the basic principle of passing information via a method/function call

Answer (score -1):

There are no such thing as Global variables, but static variables fulfill the same function. So you could create something like

```
class UserManager {
  static UserData uniqueUser;
}
```

and use it as `UserManager.uniqueUser = new UserData(name, cash)` then read the name as `UserManager.uniqueUser.Username`.

(do change the variable names to lowercase though)

Comment: Don't even get me started on what an incredibly bad idea that is, just like global variables in other languages, `static` variables in Java should be avoid where ever possible, for the same reasons

Comment: Well, don't get started then :-)  I generally agree with you, but this is a simple answer for a simple question for someone that is clearly just learning. I don't want to dump several semesters of software engineering, best practices and a few gang-of-4 patterns just to spice it up.

Comment: "hands shovel to unexpecting/inexperienced developer, says, dig here"

Comment: feel free to drop on him your 100-page answer anytime then! Be proactive rather than a critic ;-)